# Smooth line to the full datase (faceting) ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add smooth line of the **full** dataset to each facet.

However, the following code add smooth line different(of each facet) smooth line to each facet.

```
ggplot(mpg2,aes(displ,hwy)) + geom_point()  + facet_wrap(~class) + geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `geom_smooth` layer using a dataset that doesn't contain the faceting variable.  So remove `class` from the dataset.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
    geom_point()  + 
    facet_wrap(~class) + 
    geom_smooth(data = mpg[,1:10], se = FALSE)
```